# How to add relevant visual interest to an online course listing?

Tags: interaction-design, icons, image

A company sells online courses in the US that are state-specific. The course names are often very technical (due to state requirements) and the average user doesn't know which course they need until told. How would you add relevant visual interest in the form of imagery or icons within each course listing, so each listing isn't just a wall of text?

Low hanging fruit is a stock photo of someone studying online or a photo of the state (abbreviation, well-known social spot), but these seems too generic.

Any inspiration or ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: Hi Sam,
This forum works best when you show some visual examples of your efforts so far, with any context or constraints. That way the community has something tangible to weigh decisions against.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Example pic added.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what use case would you serve with adding imagery?

- If the *only* reason everyone ever looks at this list is because they are looking for a course with a specific name, **any icons would be clutter** (provide a good text search instead)
- If someone would conceivably do multiple of these courses over the course of his or her career, it might be worth having icons for "groups" of courses that might be done eventually by the same people
- If you have the situation that people remember some facts about the course they are trying to find but not the exact name (like: *I remember it being 20 Credit Hours and OIL-something*) then have some iconography relating to the facts that people most often to remember
- Having a high-level category systems and really obvious icons for people to quickly grasp what is definitely not relevant for them (like: *Ok so the orange wrench symbol means courses for mechanics, but I am a financial advisor so I scroll past all these*) might also be a good idea

I just can't stress this enough: If I am a user, already somewhat annoyed with having to find some arcane and long course name in a list you are **not** going to make me happy with some grinning people from Shutterstock ;)

Aid users in quickly finding their course first and foremost, *then* worry about aesthetics. Ideally this is not the page you want users to spend much time on anyways, right?

Hope this helps somewhat :)

Answer (score 0):

1. **Try to add categorization and icon visualization for these categories**

---

2. **You can maybe add an icon for a level/difficulty or your courses to improve the choice for your user**